# send selected date to django using htmx & pickadate.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, htmx, pickadate

I use the pickadate.js widget, to select a date. The selected date should be sent to django do query availability.

pickadate.js creates a hidden input field with `name="date_submit"`. I use jQuery to add some htmx attributes to listen on the change event of that element. That works so far and the hidden input element has all the necessary hx-attributes assigned to it. I debugged the events with `htmx.logAll();`. the 'change' event is fired on the element. However, the hx-attributes on the `hidden input field` don't have any effect and no requests are made to the django backend. The code is part of a form, placed in a modal.

rendered hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="date_submit" value="2023-05-26" hx-trigger="change" hx-get="/" hx-target="#test">
```

Date Formfield:

```
<div class="form-floating">
   {% render_field reservation_form.date class="datepicker form-control mb-3" %}
   <label for="{{ reservation_form.date.id_for_label }}">Event Date</label>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    htmx.logAll();
    var $input = $('.datepicker').pickadate({
                        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                        formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                        min: 0,
                        max: 90,
                        disable: {{ blocked_dates }},
                        firstDay: 1,

                        onOpen: function() {
                            // Get the hidden input field
                            var hiddenInput = $(this.$node).siblings('[name="date_submit"]');
                            // Add HTMX attributes to the hidden input field
                            hiddenInput.attr('hx-trigger', 'change');
                            hiddenInput.attr('hx-get', "{% url 'home' %}");
                            hiddenInput.attr('hx-target', '#test');
                        }
    });

    $input.on('change', function()
        var hiddenInput = $(this).siblings('[name="date_submit"]');
        hiddenInput.val($(this).val());
        htmx.trigger(hiddenInput[0], 'change');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you use a regular HTML date input instead?